# How does Custom Role Provider work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I am going to setup a custom role provider, but I don't have a very good idea of how it works behind the scenes.

**[Questions]**

1. What is the difference between setting roles in a form authentication ticket and using a custom role provider? Which is better to use?
2. If I create a custom role provider can I user role names in the web.config to allow / block users?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Not sure that there is a "better" choice, that has to do with the requirements of the project. I created a role provider based on Windows Authentication rather than Forms Authentication for an internal project because I didn't want to create a bunch of AD groups and I wanted Windows Auth to allow users into the site. As far as what does it do, it interacts with authenticated users to define who is allowed in what areas of the site.

2- Yes.

some additional [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx)

Comment: In master Page, Can we go for fetching the data from database and allow the use to enter/disallow on the basis of it ? and not in web.config. Is it correct ?

Comment: you could probably manage that. I think that all gets defined in the provider.